# Old own question flagged as duplicated of new own question

Tags: discussion

I had this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497206/npe-on-eclipse-debugger-attach), which received *Tumbleweed* badge:

> You've earned the "Tumbleweed" badge (Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week) for "NPE on Eclipse debugger attach".

I still had this issue, so to not start a bounty, this morning I asked same question again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671176/npe-when-debugging-android-app-in-physical-device), receiving a nice answer in less than one hour. **GREAT!** ;).

Problem is, before receiving answer in the new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671176/npe-when-debugging-android-app-in-physical-device), my original and OLD [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497206/npe-on-eclipse-debugger-attach) has been flagged as duplicated of my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671176/npe-when-debugging-android-app-in-physical-device).

Is this correct? Must I do something with it? If I delete old flagged question I will loose my badge?

Comment: Why did you ask the same question again?  You knew it was a duplicate.

Comment: Did you read my question? I knew it, but a) duplicate was the original old question when new had NO ANSWERS b) I didn't want to start a bounty and c) i'm asking what to do....

Comment: Yes, I read your question.  Just because it doesn't have answers **doesn't mean** you post the same question again.  That's what a bounty is for - to draw attention.  See [ChrisF's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286721/426671) answer below, reposting the same question because you failed to get an answer is not an appropriate use of the site.

Comment: @bluefeel It Doesn't seem you read properly... I know... I upvoted answer. But not accepted cause I asked more questions, **if you wanna focus in it's a duplicate, feel free**, but I told I already knew that, **please move forward and answer other questions or don't make noise**...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable for an older question to be closed as a duplicate of a newer one if the newer one *has better answers* than the older one.

Badges are not normally removed once they are earned. The only exception to this is tag badges. If you drop below the criteria then you lose the badge.

However, you shouldn't really be reasking the same question again. This is an abuse of the site. The way to get more notice for your question is to:

1. Edit it to make it clearer/add more information/etc. This will bump it to the home page again. Though don't continually edit the question as this will be regarded as abuse of the system.
2. Publicise it on places like Twitter, Google+, other forums.
3. Put a bounty on it.

Not wanting to put a bounty on a question is no excuse to misuse the site.

If your original question received no answers then you could delete it *before* posting a new version. However, if you just repost the same question again and people spot this it won't be well received by the community so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: thanks for the edit @ChrisF ... done with deleting old and unanswered AND thanks for next time guideline :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla - If you make a habit of deleting questions and reasking them it *will* be spotted and you might end up in a worse position.

Comment: and I knew it was wrong, I just wanted to know why this happened and how to avoid making this mistake again... Thanks again...

Comment: "if the newer one has better answers than the older one" or the newer question more clearly asks the question more clearly, or would act as a better canonical question.